# How to use PHP and Twitter to reward users when they send a tweet using your application?

Tags: php, twitter

I've never made an application on twitter before. But when I do I want to use PHP and Twitter to award users when they send a tweet using my application.

So for example.

User clicks on "Tweet for bonus **insert_stuff_here**" link.

User then allows app to use they're twitter.

~*Tweet gets posted*~

PHP detects that <-- somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the twitter API then when you post the users tweet on their behalf you can run your code at the same time to award a bonus.
you will need to create a twitter application and create a oAuth key.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

People here aren't going to write a whole script for you when you haven't even attempted it yourself... i would suggest you do some research attempt some code, and if you get stuck then post what you have so far :-)

Comment: Urm, thanks. But the part after the links was not needed. I was not asking for code, I was just asking how to do it. But anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: yea a bit unnecessary I searched looking for the same thing and I wasn't looking for code.